# How to check if an element is into view using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, js-scrollintoview

I have to check if an element is in view and if not, only then scroll it into view using following and then interact with it -

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

If an element is in view, don't execute above command. To check if an element is in view, `isDisplayed()` is not helping because it returns true irrespective of an element is in view or not.

Can you please suggest what will help to achieve to check if an element is in view?

Comment: isDisplayed should work. Have you checked this cases: 1. Opacity of the element is 0.  2.The element is visible but covered by another.


Give a try with driver.findElement(By.id("idOfElement")).isDisplayed(); Or check size driver.findElements(by).size() > 0 to determine if the element is displayed.

Comment: Refer this for a good answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244889/1728790

Comment: Also this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646195/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible-with-webdriver

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525678/4513879

Comment: @demouser123, thanks for pointing to answers. I really helped!

Answer (score 1):

To interact with an element the element needs to be within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). If the element is not within the *Viewport* you have to `scroll()` as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

> You can find a detailed discussion on different scrolling option in [What is the difference between the different scroll options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339)

---

At this point it is worth to mention, the following methods:

- [moveToElement()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)  and other methods from [Actions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Class
- [elementToBeClickable()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) from [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) Class

will automatically **scroll** the element within the *Viewport* before getting executed.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium python Error: element could not be scrolled into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085152/selenium-python-error-element-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view)

---

Finally, in the rarest of the rare cases if the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) comprises of [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](https://reactjs.org/) elements you may even have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` before you attempt to scroll as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button.nsg-button"))));
```