# Selenium findElement throws exception when element present in page but not visible in viewport

Tags: java, selenium

The following code works perfectly when an element is present in DOM and visible in the viewport:

```
WebElement button = webdriver.findElement(By.id("myButton"));
```

But, I don't understand why it throws an exception when the button is present in the DOM but not visible in the viewport.

I know for sure that the button is present: there is no ajax in play here.

How can I test for an element to be present in the DOM whether or not it is visible in the viewport?

I already saw some usefull links here on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916498/420593

[How to check if an element is into view using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316819/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-into-view-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Have you tried with Explicit Wait?

Comment: yes ` WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 3);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("myButton")));` But without any result.

Comment: is url public accesible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDriverWait along with action class to move to element and perform click onto it.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement button = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("myButton")));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, that's my conclusion:

```
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", button);
button.click();
```

Should work, but in my case, due to some bootstrap fixed header, the button is in the view but hidden by the fixed header over it (z-index). And an exception is thrown when the second line is executed.

Same occurred with the following:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

So, I finally resolved my problem by simulating a click in javascript:

```
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", button);
```